# ASP.NET Core transient DbContext

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

I have multiple hosted services each working with the database. I was getting the DbConcurrencyException, since all the hosted services were using the same instance of the dbContext simultaneously (at the start of the application).
I've resolved this issue by changing the lifetime of the dbContext from scoped to transient. What did I really change by this? Will the application connect and disconnect from the database each time I work with the dbContext? If not, is there any other issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IHostedService` or `BackgroundService` are `singletons`. Also, by default DBContext (when you run `AddDbContext`) is `scoped` service. So in each hosted service, you need to open a scope using `IServiceScopeFactory`. Like this:

```
using var scope = _scopeFactory.CreateScope();
var dbContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<YourDbContext>;
```

Regarding your question about what it has changed when you registered it as `transient`. Each time you inject and call DBContext it will instantiate a new DbContext. When the service is scoped, during `one scope` if you are going to call DBContext multiple times, you will get the same instance of DBContext, which will improve performance, so maybe this is what you need?

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much. So I should keep the DbContext scoped, but instead of injecting it into the hosted services directly, I should do what you show in the code snippet. Right?

Comment: @sudoman281 exactly. Also, keep in mind and do not inject into IHostedService anything except instances registered as singletons, all scoped/transient instances should be fetched through IServiceScopeFactory

Comment: Didn't know that. Thanks a lot! :-)